# what is the difference between Gateway URI and Dispatcher URI in cognos

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

what is the difference between Gateway URI  and  Dispatcher URI  in cognos ?
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/framework-manager-cognos-analytics-single-sign-sso-gateway-uri
Why the  gateway URI needs a  alias ? What is that for?

Comment: Gateway URI is for the entire instance, it resolves to a web server. It's used here for authentication and authorization. Each individual dispatcher has it's own URI, just pick one for the FM config. The dispatcher URI is used for actually publishing the package.